# Content provider for combo box in javafx?

Tags: java, combobox, javafx

I would like to bind my business logic to a combo box in javafx.
For instance, assume I have a `CustomObject` that has children I can get with the `getChildren()` method that return `Collection<BusinessObjects>`.

Now I want to bind that collection to the dropbox so that my business objects will appear in the combo with the help of some string adapter.

I see that there are observable lists I can use but my current business model doesn't use them....

So how can the combo track my business model?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this probably:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class ComboBoxDemo extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ComboBox<Student> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();

        University university = new University(1, Arrays.asList(new Student(1, "John"),
                new Student(2, "Joe")));


        comboBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                university.getStudents()
        ));

        comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        Label label = new Label();

        comboBox.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            label.setText(newValue.getId() + " :: " + newValue.getName());
        });

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setSpacing(5);
        hBox.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(comboBox, label);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(hBox, 320, 240));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private class University {
        int id;

        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

        public University(int id, List<Student> students) {
            this.id = id;
            this.students = students;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public List<Student> getStudents() {
            return students;
        }

        public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
            this.students = students;
        }

        public void addStudent(Student student) {
            this.students.add(student);
        }
    }

    private class Student {
        int id;
        String name;

        public Student(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Student() {
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

So we have a `University` entity that can have multiple `Student` entities.
We create instance of `University` and populate it with instances of `Student` class. Then we set collection of students to `ComboBox` and observe `valueProperty` for changes. Upon selection, we display details about student in `Label`. Note that, what will be displayed in `ComboBox` depends on value that `toString` method returns. In this case, `toString` is overriden to return only a name of `Student`. However, upon selection, I get whole `Student` object (not just a name).

Comment: From the javadocs of ObservableList() method:
Constructs an ObservableList that is backed by the specified list. Mutation operations on the ObservableList instance will be reported to observers that have registered on that instance.
Note that mutation operations made directly to the underlying list are not reported to observers of any ObservableList that wraps it.

Meaning that changes to University object will not be shown -> :(